# get IDs of leaf categories

Tags: php, tree

I need to get IDs of all leaf-children category IDs, parameter for `getLastChildren()` is ID of current category and I need all leafs under it. I tried something like this, but it ended up with infinite loop. `$categoryList` is container of `CategoryItem` objects, which can return all children categories and also find parent of current category. `$category->isLastChild()` will return true/false if current category is leaf. Thanks for help.

```
/**
 * @param int $idCategory
 * @return int[]
 */
public function getLastChildren($idCategory)
{
    $categoryList = $this->getCategoryList();
    $categories = $categoryList->getChildCategories($idCategory);
    $leafCats = [];
    $nonLeafCats = [];
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $nonLeafCats[] = $category->getId();
    }
    while (!empty($nonLeafCats)) {
        foreach ($nonLeafCats as &$nonLeafCat) {
            $categories = $categoryList->getChildCategories($nonLeafCat);
            $result = $this->getChildren($categories);
            $leafCats = array_merge($leafCats, $result['leafs']);
            $nonLeafCats = array_merge($nonLeafCats, $result['nonLeafs']);
            unset($nonLeafCat);
        }
    }
    return $leafCats;
}

/**
 * @param CategoryItem[] $categories
 * @return array
 */
private function getChildren(array $categories)
{
    $leafCats = $nonLeafCats = [];
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if ($category->isLastChild()) {
            $leafCats[] = $category->getId();
        } else {
            $nonLeafCats[] = $category->getId();
        }
    }
    return [
        'leafs' => $leafCats,
        'nonLeafs' => $nonLeafCats
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solution:

```
/**
 * @param int $idCategory
 * @return int[]
 */
public function getLastChildren($idCategory)
{
    if(empty($this->categoryList)) {
        $this->categoryList = $this->getCategoryList();
    }
    $categories = $this->categoryList->getChildCategories($idCategory);
    $leafs = [];
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if ($category->isLastChild()) {
            $leafs[] = $category->getId();
        } else {
            $leafs = array_merge($leafs, $this->getLastChildren($category->getId()));
        }
    }
    return $leafs;
}
```